# How to Sort the Bugs

Tags: pattern, story

There have been a lot more proto-bugs growing in the water at the bathhouse. Some of them have been caught, and you've been sent to sort them by kingdom. Unfortunately for you, you haven't been given any rules or tests to determine the kingdom of these creatures; all you have is a small table of 15 examples:
[image: Table]
*minerals left, plants middle, animals right*

**What are the rules to classify these diverse bugs?**

Comment: The image is actually huge with artificially inflated pixels.  Is this intentional?

Comment: @FlorianF Yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's sort out the phenotypes.

> There are 3 body types, 3 sides, 3 bottoms and 3x3 tops.
>
>  - Body type is blue, green (greenish), or brown.
>  The brown body is short, green and blue are long.
>  The greenish color could be meant as an intermediate between blue and brown.
>
>  - Side appendages are none, wings/leaves, or legs.
>  The number of legs reflects the body size, 3 or 4.
>
>  - The bottom appendages are none, one long or two short.
>
>  - The top appendage is a combination of two properties.
>  The general shape is none, single or triple.
>  The tips are also none, single pointed or triple.
>
>  There are 3 of each property.

What to do with it all?

> It seems that each property can be absent.  If we count brown as absent (it's shorter), then the rule for mineral, the left column, could be that only 2 properties are present.

Here is a possible criteria for the classification

> Minerals have a majority of features absent, i.e. max of 2 visible features.
>
>  Vegetal features are: body: green, sides: leaves, bottom: single, top: triple, tips: triple.
>
>  Animal features are: body: blue, sides: legs, bottom: double, top: single, tips: single.
>
>  If there are 3 or more visible features: if there are more animal features than vegetal features, then it is an animal.  If there are more or as many vegetal features as animal features, then it is a vegetal.

Comment: The mineral rule is correct

Comment: The rules for animals and plants are correct, but you haven't said what it is when it is evenly split between animal and plant features

Comment: I improved the wording.